# Pandas Create a new Column which takes the Most Frequent item Description given Item Codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| Group | UPC | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 246 | 1234568 | Chips BBQ |
| 158 | 7532168 | Cereal Honey |
| 246 | 9876532 | Chips Ketchup |
| 665 | 8523687 | Strawberry Jam |
| 246 | 1234568 | Chips BBQ |
| 158 | 5553215 | Cereal Chocolate |

I want to replace the descriptions of the items with the most frequent description based on the group # or the first instance if there is a tie.

So in the example above: Chips Ketchup (1 instance) is replaced with Chips BBQ (2 instances) And Cereal Chocolate is replaced with Cereal Honey (First Instance).

Desired output would be:

| Group | UPC | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 246 | 1234568 | Chips BBQ |
| 158 | 7532168 | Cereal Honey |
| 246 | 9876532 | Chips BBQ |
| 665 | 8523687 | Strawberry Jam |
| 246 | 1234568 | Chips BBQ |
| 158 | 5553215 | Cereal Honey |

If this is too complicated I can settle for replacing with simply the first instance without taking frequency into consideration at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df['Description'] = df.groupby('Group')['Description'].transform(lambda s: s.value_counts().index[0])
```

It seems like `Series.value_counts` (unlike `Series.mode`, which I also tried) orders elements that occur the same number of times by their first occurence. This behavior is not documented so I'm not sure you can rely on it.